# Handling a large dataset consisting of npy files

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have a high number of npy files (448 files) each consisting of around 12k frames (150x150 RGB images) which together make the input to my neural network (X). However, since it is impossible to load all of the files into a single array, and the fact that it is necessary to shuffle all of the samples to avoid bias, how do I create the input and feed it to the network? Someone suggested creating a dummy array to represent indices, shuffle that, create chunks based on the array size and the indices and then feed the chunks to the neural network. However, I was wondering if there is another simpler method. And also I am familiar with Tensorflow(+keras) and PyTorch.
So in a word, I would like to do this step but with a high number of large npy files:

```py
X_train_filenames, X_val_filenames, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(...)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to shuffle between each `.npy` file? I mean IMO it should be enough to go `12_000` shuffled samples, followed by another `12_000` shuffled samples and so on? Each time, `12_000` would be different `.npy` file. How much RAM memory do you have, is it enough to fit at least one `.npy`?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke yes actually, the idea is to shuffle all of the samples along with their output. I already found a solution, using TFrecords, but I'm yet to find out how